# Oracle Table level partition - add INTERVAL to existing partition by range

Tags: oracle, partition

I have some tables in an Oracle database which I have partitioned by range. It seems that the default interval of partition is 1 day.
I want to update this to use `INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(5,'DAY'))` so that the partition is created for every 5 days and not every day.

How do I update my existing script which uses only "Partition by range" and not uses partition by range interval. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

with

```
alter table … set interval(NUMTODSINTERVAL(5,'DAY'))
```

you should be able to this in current Oracle Releases: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html

Comment: Thanks Martin. I tried this, but I am not finding it in the DDL or partition tab in sql developer after running this alter table statement.How can I ensure that this has taken effect?

Comment: Not finding what? Anyway have a look in `user_part_tables` and `user_tab_partitions`.

Comment: Or `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type => 'TABLE', name => 'YOURTABLENAME', schema => user ) from dual;` and ignore the irrelevant details.